# Permutation in python

Tags: python, permutation

I am running python 3.0 and need to make a permutation from a list of 7 numbers in that list, but I am not finding any decent sample code or guide to create all the permutations.

Could someone please put some sample code as to how I would make and be able to print all the permutations.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Comment: For *not finding* you probably meant that you did not *search*. Searching `python permutations` on google gives the documentation for `itertools` as first result.

Answer (score 2):

[Itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) has combinations and [permutations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).